# How to handle duplicate Pandas DataFrame columns when also specifying dtype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am parsing some data with predefined columns, and sometimes these columns are duplicated e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B']], columns=['A','A'])
```

The above works just fine, but I want to also specify the dtype for the column e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B']], columns=['A','A'],dtype={'A':str})
```

However, the above errors out with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 513, in __init__
    dtype = self._validate_dtype(dtype)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 345, in _validate_dtype
    dtype = pandas_dtype(dtype)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py", line 1799, in pandas_dtype
    npdtype = np.dtype(dtype)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 62, in _usefields
    names, formats, offsets, titles = _makenames_list(adict, align)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 30, in _makenames_list
    n = len(obj)
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid, irrespective of the duplicated columns, the [`dtype` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) expects a **single dtype**.

> **dtype**  dtype, default None
>
> Data type to force. **Only a single dtype is allowed.** If None, infer.

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','B']], columns=['A','A']).astype({'A':str})
```